# Redistribute radiobuttons with variable text length equally in a radiogroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-layout-weight

I have a radiogroup with horizontal orientation. It has 3 radio buttons and I would like them all to occupy the equal amount of space. When I give layout_weight=1 to each radiobutton, they look like this

[image]

Here, the layout_weight just adds equal space to each button irrespective of the text length.
I want the radiobuttons to look like this

[image]

Comment: have u added layout_width to 0. Also all those in linearlayout with weightsum for that is 1 and then give weight to every group, as reqd.

Comment: set width of all the radio buttons as 0dp

Comment: Sumant can you put that as an answer? I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u added `layout_width` to 0. Also all those in LinearLayout with `weightsum` for that is 1 and then give weight to every group, as required.